# Merge two rows in SQL for-fitting one column field

Tags: sql

I have 2 Rows on a Table

```
Device_ID    Other_ID
========     ========
633          1
232          2
242          2
```

I need the following results:

```
Device_ID    Other_ID
========     ========
633          1
232          2
```

How can this be done in SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT min(Device_ID) AS Device_ID, Other_ID
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY Other_ID
ORDER  BY Other_ID;
```

Comment: You are very welcome. I have written answers that took me hours and got less appraisal. ;)